# changing analog pins data logging using sdFat library

Tags: analogread, data-type, datalogging

Background:

My goal is to use sdFat library, more precisely AnalogBinLogger example.

I want to log data from changing analog pins for example, I want to log from pin 0 to pin 3 for 5 minutes and then from pin 4 to pin 6 for another 5 mins and then from pin 7 to pin 9 for another 5 mins. that is going to be continuously which means I am going to get rid of the part where you have to enter "r" to start logging.

Regarding the time, I managed to figure it out, I am just using the value of the variable count, if my sampling rate is 1000 samples/sec for example then 5 minutes will be 1000*60*5 and the change will be done in this line:

```
if (Serial.available()) {
  // Stop ISR calls.
  adcStop();
```

to

```
if (count >1000*60*5) {
  // Stop ISR calls.
  adcStop();
```

and this worked fine.

My problem is with the changing pins:

```
const uint8_t PIN_LIST[] = {1};
```

I changed this line to

```
uint8_t PIN_LIST[3] = {};
```

First I removed the word `const`, because it's not going to be constant anymore, and I just declared an empty array, and second I am changing the pins in the loop.

Here is the loop after I got rid of doing the serial input:

```
void loop(void) {
int i;
for (i=0;i<=12;i+3)
{   
  PIN_LIST[] = {i,i+1,i+2};
  logData();
  Serial.println("done");
 }}
```

The problem is I get this error :

1. AnalogBinLogger.ino: In function 'void loop()':
2. AnalogBinLogger:808: error: expected primary-expression before ']'
   token
3. AnalogBinLogger:808: error: expected primary-expression before '{'
   token
4. AnalogBinLogger:808: error: expected `;' before '{' token

The line 808 is:

```
PIN_LIST[] = {i,i+1,i+2};
```

So this is the only error, any help please?

The code is so long (800+ lines) if this information is not enough and you need me to explain a part then just tell me.

Answer (score 1):

in case someone has the same problem
it seems like after you initialize an array this way

uint8_t PIN_LIST[3] = {};

you won't be able to assign all the values at once:

PIN_LIST[] = {i,i+1,i+2};
instead you assign each individual value

- PIN_LIST[0] = i;
- PIN_LIST[1] = i+1;
- PIN_LIST[2] = i+2;

and now it worked : )